# Не работает вставка текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, вставляет в начало `textarea` имя юзера. Работает при пустом `textarea`, если в него что-то написать, то ничего не вставляется. Ошибок в логах нет

```
function reply(name){
$('#textarea').prepend(name+', ');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#textarea').val(function(index, old) { return name + old; });